# ng-repeat shows my array updated from server two or more times

Tags: arrays, angularjs, dynamic, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use an Array uploaded dynamically from server using Ajax.

```
$scope.ChangeArray = function(detail) {
    ajaxRequest('myAjax',
                {
                    shipping: detail
                },
                function(results) {
                    var myarray = [];

                    angular.forEach(results, function(e) {              
                        myarray.push({id: e.id,T: e.T,W: e.W});
                    });

                    $scope.editingBoxes.entries = myarray;

                    $scope.$apply();
                    $scope.editingBoxes.NumberofBoxes = results.length;
                    console.log($scope.editingBoxes.entries);
                }
            );

            $scope.editingBoxesIndex = -1;
            $scope.editingBoxes = detail;
```

All results are agree each time I'get in my array the data I need.

Now when I try to write data to a table

```
                <tr ng-repeat='box in editingBoxes.entries'>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-square" ng-click='deleteBoxEntry(box)'>
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                </td>
                <td style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" ng-model='box.id'>
                </td>
                <td >
                <input type="text" ng-model='box.TrackNumber'>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model='box.Weight'></td>
            </tr>
```

Now if the first option I take have 2 rows, my following selection show 2 times all the rows in my new array.

If I select an first option with 5 rows, my following selection will show my new table content five times.

And so on ....

Any Idea?

I'm really frustrated.

Comment: Why are you calling `$apply`, you are using angularJs. You are supposed ti use `$http`. Please take a look at digest cycle of angularJS to avoid pit falls. If possible provide a plnkr.co

Comment: I've just probe with $http and really it is not necessary using $apply but heaving the same behavior

Comment: I can try to provide quick solution if you can share your angularJS code. IF possible please provide a similar working example on https://plnkr.co/ to make it quicker.